# $f(x)g(x)\equiv{a}\pmod{b}$ (How do I solve a congruence where one side is the product of polynomials)?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm looking for how I would go about solving
\begin{align*}
f(x)g(x)\equiv{a}\pmod{b}
\end{align*}
I am given $a$, $b$, and $f(x)$, so the problem is centered around finding $g(x)$ if possible. So far I've approached by seeing what happens when $f(x)$ is degree one (since setting it to an integer makes the problem trivial because the coefficients of $g$ don't "interact" at all). However, I'm not making much leeway here. What would be the best approach for finding $g(x)$?

Worked out (requested in comment):

Suppose $f(x)=x+2$, $a=3$, $b=7$. I would set $g(x)=m_nx^n+\ldots+m_0$ and multiply.
\begin{align*}
m_nx^{n+1}+(m_{n-1}+2m_n)x^n+\ldots+(m_0+2m_1)x+2m_0\equiv3\pmod7
\end{align*}
$3$ is the same as $3+0x+0x^2+\ldots+0x^n$ so
\begin{align*}
2m_0\equiv3\pmod7\\
m_0+2m_1\equiv0\pmod7\\
m_1+2m_2\equiv0\pmod7\\
\ldots\\
m_{n-1}+2m_n\equiv0\pmod7\\
m_n\equiv0\pmod7
\end{align*}
And after this point I just solve the congruences from the top. If there doesn't exist $g(x)$ the solutions start cycling or repeating the same nonzero value(s), but if there is one there eventually the $m_i$are only 0 $\pmod7$. In this case, $m_0\equiv5\pmod7$, $m_1\equiv1\pmod7$, $m_2\equiv3\pmod7$, $m_3\equiv1\pmod7$, and after this it keeps cycling between 3 and 1, so I know that there is not a solution for $g(x)$.

Comment: you ought to provide one worked example, as the question is ambigous

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip. I'll add that.

Comment: polynomial remainder theorem.

Comment: @WillJagy I added a worked out example that shows how I'm trying to find $g(x)$

Comment: @Fiveier With your example, if you start at the bottom & work up, you'll get $m_n \equiv 0 \pmod 7$, $m_{n-1} \equiv 0 \pmod 7$, $m_{n-2} \equiv 0 \pmod 7$, ..., $m_{1} \equiv 0 \pmod 7$ and $m_{0} \equiv 0 \pmod 7$. However, this last one contradicts the first congruence equation of $2m_{0} \equiv 3 \pmod 7$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Gotcha. Would it be better to approach this way when I suspect that there's a $g(x)$ that works, though? How would that look? As a side note, how do I know when $g(x)$ exists?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Could you describe more how I would use it? It seems like polynomial remainder theorem is mainly used for finding roots or factoring polynomials but I'm looking for a polynomial with no knowledge of its roots. Unless there's a way to translate this congruence into something about its factorization that I'm not seeing?

Comment: @Fiveier As it'll involve just one unknown, starting from the highest coefficient being congruent to $0$ will, I believe, often be somewhat easier to work with. As for knowing whether or not a $g(x)$ exists, I think in most cases a linear function, not just $f(x) = x + 2$, unless the constant term is congruent to $0$, will result in a contradiction. However, I believe this will not usually be true for most polynomials of higher degree. Unfortunately, what you're doing not something I've ever studied or worked on before, so I don't know if I can help you much more than what I stated so far.

Comment: @JohnOmielan This is already plenty of help. More of it would spoil the fun :)

Comment: Use CRT to reduce to $b = p^n = $ prime power, then use Hensel lifting or Newton iteration.